# What is the co-efficient of $x^3y^4z^5$ in the expansion of $(xy+yz+zx)^6$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

I came across this problem and I was not able to think of a way to solve this. I tried to find a pattern by simplifying $(xy+yz+zx)^2$ and then extrapolating the results for the $6^{th}$ power but that also didn't help me. Can someone please tell me how to solve these kinds of problem?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Look at "multinomial expansions", for instance: here: https://mathonweb.com/help_ebook/html/expressions_8.htm

Comment: Previously asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/305737/321264. Several similar questions, like https://math.stackexchange.com/q/484908/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2592558/321264

Answer (score 2):

write the expression in the form: $[y(x+z)+zx]^6$. The term with the 4th power of $y$ is:
$$
\binom64 y^4(x+z)^4(zx)^2=\binom64 y^4(x^4+4x^3z +6x^2z^2+4xz^3+z^4)z^2x^2
$$
Thus the coeffecient of $x^3y^4z^5$ is:
$$
4\binom64 
$$